# Fetching multidimensional array

Tags: php

despite my efforts I wasn't able to find a suitable solution. Here is the problem:

All the data comes from a form with text fields named `name[]`, `gender[]`, and `age[]`.

`print_r($_POST)` looks like:

```
[name] => Array ([2] => Adam [6] => Suzy )
[gender] => Array ( [2] => male [6] => female )
[age] => Array ( [2] => 30 [6] => 25 )
```

I am trying to iterate it like this:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
echo $value['name'].$value['gender'].$value['age']."<br>";
}
```

The result should look like this:

Adam - male - 30
Suzy - female - 25

Comment: where you got this php `array` structure ?

Comment: Is it really multidimensional array ???

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're starting with? `$array` as you have it written will not parse. Is this your actual code? Are you asking how to define the array, or do you already have an array (somewhat) like what you've shown and you're asking how to iterate/output it?

Comment: Lets say I have a from with multiple rows. Each row is containing 3 text fields filled with name, gender and age. by select few of them and post for processing I am getting the arrays I posted. I solved this question once 5-6 yrs ago but cant remember how :)

Comment: @MiroArsov I updated the question with the info from your comments. Please feel free to re-edit if it's not to your liking.

Comment: [link]http://arsov.com/test.php[/link]

Answer (score 2):

You are close - but the syntax for creating arrays is slightly different.

```
$array = array (
   array('name' => 'Adam', 'gender' => 'male', 'age' => 30),
   array('name' => 'Suzy', 'gender' => 'female', 'age' => 25),
);
foreach ($array as $value)
{
   echo $value['name'].$value['gender'].$value['age']."<br>";
}
```

You've got two options - you could create an array of two items; each has three details about a single person. That's what I did and it suits the loop you've shown.

Or you can have three parallel arrays - one with two names, one with two genders and one with two ages.
That second way would look more like:

```
$array = array(
  'name' => array('Adam','Suzy'),
  'gender' => array('male','female'),
  'age' =>  array(30,25)
);
```

But it would be harder to get the output you want from that.

```
$array2 = array(
  'name' => array('Adam','Suzy'),
  'gender' => array('male','female'),
  'age' =>  array(30,25)
);

for($i=0;$i<count($array2['name']);$i++){
  echo $array2['name'][$i].$array2['gender'][$i].$array2['age'][$i].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: We should be encourging people to use the new(ish) array syntax imo.
`$array = ['value1', 'value2'];`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! All the data comes from a form with text fields and the arrays are name[], gender[], and age[].

Comment: [name] => Array
        (
            [2] => Adam
            [6] => Suzy
        )

    [gender] => Array
        (
            [2] => male
            [6] => female
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [2] => 30
            [6] => 25
        )

This is exactly how my print_r($_POST) looks like!

Comment: Yep, that one was tested about an hr ago. Doesnt work...
`code`
     [name] => Array ( [2] => Adam [6] => Suzy )
     [gender] => Array ( [2] => male [6] => female ) 
     [age] => Array ( [2] => 30 [6] => 25 )
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Each of the arrays in `$_POST` have the same set of keys:

```
$_POST = array(
    'name' =>   array(2 => 'Adam', 6 => 'Suzy'),
    'gender' => array(2 => 'male', 6 => 'female'),
    'age' =>    array(2 => '30',   6 => '25')
)
```

You can iterate one of the inner arrays, and use its key to access the corresponding values in the other arrays.

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $name) {
    echo $name . $_POST['gender'][$key] . $_POST['age'][$key] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Not working in what way? What does it do? Are there errors?

Comment: I tried out the link. The $_POST values show up as expected, and I don't see any errors, but there's no output besides that when submitting the form. Are you using the `foreach` loop from this answer on that page, or something else?

Comment: <form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="gender[]"/>
<input type="text" name="age[]"/>
<br />
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="gender[]"/>
<input type="text" name="age[]"/>

<input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: <?
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
$array2 = array(
  $name,$gender, $age
);

for($i=0;$i<count($array2['name']);$i++){
  echo $array2['name'][$i].$array2['gender'][$i].$array2['age'][$i].'<br/>';
}
?>

Comment: Tell me what is this..... I am writing since 2002(ocasionaly) and never had such issu. The problem can be solved "dumb" way of course!

Comment: It's kind of hard to read in comments, but it looks like the `$name`,`$gender`, and `$age` variables you're using  in that code have not been set. Have you tried accessing `$_POST` directly as I suggested?

Comment: `code` <? echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"?> shows what's posted

Comment: As you suggested works, but I need the values POSTED sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $id=>$value)
{
    echo $value . $gender[$id] . $age[$id] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I've modified the array structure that you posted on your question because it is not **valid** for in `php`. Then If I don't misunderstood you requirements then you've this array structure and you want to archive this-

```
<?php
$array = array (
    'name'=>array('Adam', 'Suzy'),
    'gender'=>array('male', 'female'),
    'age'=>array(30, 25)
);
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{   
    if($i==2)break;
    echo $array['name'][$i]."-".$array['gender'][$i] ."-". $array['age'][$i] ."<br>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
$array = array (
    'name'=>array('Adam', 'Suzy'),
    'gender'=>array('male', 'female'),
    'age'=>array(30, 25)
);

foreach ($array['name'] as $index=>$name)
{   
    echo $name."-".$array['gender'][$index] ."-". $array['age'][$index] ."\n";
}
?>
```

**Program Output:**

```
Adam-male-30
Suzy-female-25
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1039966

Answer (score 0):

@Being Sunny
Veeeery close to that sir I'v used back in 2003. Here is the working solution:

```
<?
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";


foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $name) {
    echo "NAME=".$_POST['name'][$key]."gender=" . $_POST['gender'][$key] . "AGE=".$_POST['age'][$key] . "<br>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
WOKSING SOLUTION:
<code>echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";


foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $name) {
    echo "NAME=".$_POST['nemae'][$key]."gender=" . $_POST['gender'][$key] . "AGE=".$_POST['age'][$key] . "<br>";
}
</code>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="gender[]"/>
<input type="text" name="age[]"/>
<br />
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="gender[]"/>
<input type="text" name="age[]"/>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```